# Why would node.js not close a file after writing with writeFileSync?

Tags: node.js, writefile, data-integrity

(OS=Windows) I was having issues with power failures while processing very large files. If the power went out, then my log file would be all zeros (NUL NUL NUL...). So, I wrote a couple lines to save the progress every 50K lines, so that in the event of a power failure I can then restart from the last successful line.

```
toggle = toggle ^ 1
fs.writeFileSync(`progress${toggle}.txt`, progress)
```

Toggle alternates between 1 and 0. This way, if the power happens to go out while progress1.txt is being saved, I will still have progress0.txt. And vice-versa. I tested this and it works correctly. It toggles between the two files and saves progress. Then, after the power went out, I checked and BOTH progress files were all NULs. Not just one script, but all the scripts had their progress files overwritten with NULs.

According to my research this happens when a computer is suddenly shut off while writing to a file. How is it possible that both files could be open at the same time? In order for progress1 to be open, writeFileSync would have to save and close progress0 and then process another 50K lines since everything is being done sync style. There should be no way for both to open at the same time.

Thank you.

**EDIT** I was asked if I can show how writeFileSync is being called. Here is the basic program structure:

```
var module = {
  finish_cb: null,
  toggle: 0,
  progress: 0,
  start_batch: function () {
    this.toggle = this.toggle ^ 1
    fs.writeFileSync(`progress${toggle}.txt`, this.progress)
  },
  process_batch: function () {
    while (STILL PROCESSING) {
      // DO BATCH THINGS
      // THIS WILL TAKE 10-20 seconds to complete
    }
    this.progress++
    this.finish_cb()
  }
}

module.finish_cb = finish
module.start_batch()
module.process_batch()

function finish () {
  if (ALL DONE) {
    console.log('All done!')
  } else {
    module.start_batch()
    module.process_batch()
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the steps I need to take to reproduce this?  Do I actually need to cut the power to my machine?  I presume there's an easier way to reproduce it.  Or does this actually only happen in the event of a power failure?

Comment: That was going to be my next question - how do you simulate a power failure without shutting off your power supply? I assumed there is no way to reproduce, so I was only hoping to gain insight into how both files could be open at the same time.

Comment: Because you are not using file descriptors `writeFileSync` will open the file, write to it, and then close it. The issue could be how you are calling it? Can you show how that?

Comment: I can't upload the entire program, but I can outline the program structure.

Comment: @about14sheep I added the program structure to the question, thank you.

Comment: Does your platform have a write-cache at the OS level?  Most operating systems buffer the data to be written and actually flush it to persistent storage a short time after the write was made.  This improves performance when writes are continual (as in your case).  But if you frequently experience power loss, you may want to disable write caching at the OS level (at the expense of performance, but in favour of data integrity.)

Comment: the logic you posted has some issues with scope. When you use a fat-arrow `() => {}` function to define an object method you loose the context of `this`. Maybe try updating to remove those in the module object to get more expected behavior.

Comment: @Wyck Thank you for the write caching suggestion. That may fix the problem, but I was hoping to understand how writeFileSync could open two files at once.

Comment: @about14sheep My actual program uses this style `start_batch: function () { ... }` I only wrote fat-arrows because I was trying to make it more readable here, and I thought => was just a shortcut for a nameless function. Do nameless functions have this same fat-arrow scope issue?

Comment: What is your operating system, filesystem type and storage medium?

Comment: anything declared with fat-arrow syntax does not have its own bindings to `this` or `super`. They should not be used in methods. You can read more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: @Wyck Windows 7 and Windows 10, both use NTFS and run on SSDs

Comment: What is the nature of the process_batch function? Is it completely synchronous?

Comment: @DaveNewton The only possible async function is a call to an http-request. But my understanding is that the http-request (or any async call) should branch off on its own while the main function should continue. How could any async function affect the basic sync program flow? And even if it did, how could this explain 4 different scripts all having their both progress files (8 total, 2 alternating per script) all be NULed out after a power out?